# Python key binding/capture

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, keyboard

I'd like to know the simplest way to bind keys in python

for example, the default python console window apears and waits, then in psuedo ->

```
if key "Y" is pressed:
   print ("Yes")
if key "N" is pressed:
   print ("No")
```

I would like to achieve this **without** the use of any **modules** not included by python. just pure python

Any and all help is greatly appreciated

python 2.7 or 3.x Windows 7

**Note:** `raw_input()` requires the user to hit enter and is therefore not keybinding

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/ (although a bit simplified):

```
class _Getch:
    """Gets a single character from standard input.  Does not echo to the
screen."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.impl = _GetchUnix()
    def __call__(self): 
        return self.impl()


class _GetchUnix:
    def __init__(self):
        import tty, sys
    def __call__(self):
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

getch = _Getch()
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> getch()
'Y' # Here I typed Y
```

This is great as it doesn't need any 3rd party modules.

Comment: which version of python is this intended for?

Comment: Thanks! this will help alot :D

Comment: The link(`code.activestate`) seems dead says bad request. Also should I do: `print(getch.__call__())
`@TerryA

Comment: @alper Link still seems to work for me,and no you justneed to do `getch()`

Comment: Thanks, link seems working but when I tried few more times I keep getting: `Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Apache Server at aardvark.activestate.com Port 80` error.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the way to do it with Tkinter which is a module included in the python install is here:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x400")
window.title("Test")

def test(event):
    print("Hi")

window.bind("a", test)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a screen, you might like this:

```
screen = turtle.Screen()
def blabla:
    # your code here
screen.listen()
screen.onkey(blabla, "(any key here)")
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. Since this is an old question, it would help if you explained why someone might prefer your answer to one of the other existing answers.

Comment: @divibisan, I don't know of a requirement that a question be new to add an answer to it, or that it has to be "better" than an existing answer for some reason.  I appreciate alternate approaches in SO.  However, I wish this answer worked out of the box.  I've never seen turtle before and it'd be cool if the code above was an MWE.