# Get Key Code of Pressed Key from Python

Tags: python, operating-system, stdin, key-bindings, sys

Is it possible to get python to read a key (such as Enter or Escape or an Arrow Key) pressed by the user and to record the keycode of that key in a variable?

I looked at this [Python key binding/capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807693/python-key-binding) but this only displays the character that you press in the shell. I want to record this value in a variable, no need to print it (and not the python '\n' for Enter but the real keycode (like 13 I think it is on Windows) for the Enter key).

Comment: use the ord() function it gets the python key code, in a number.

Comment: @MosheRabaev It doesn't work on a Mac though for me...it says that I dont' have the right encoding or something. Also, how do I use a unicode int in ord() ?

Comment: @MosheRabaev The reason I ask for the unicode thing is because you can't check a key like "Enter" with ord() .... can you?

Comment: you could ord('\r') gives you 13 as you said.

Comment: @MosheRabaev What if I need to do it for the arrow keys though? Like in my program I need to be able to pick up (in total): arrow keys, Enter key, Space key. Is there a way I can pick all of those up?

Comment: You can use w,a,s,d keys for up, left, down, right respectively, and for space use '\w'.

Comment: @MosheRabaev Oh I see. Good thinking :))))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85474/discussion-between-yello-four-and-moshe-rabaev).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. @MosheRabaev was right and this is just the code version. I guess you just have to find the characters for all the special keys (like the '\r' for Enter). No clue what the characters are for arrow keys though...

```
import wx
user_input = str(raw_input())

user_input += '\r' #If they press the Enter Key
print user_input

if ord(user_input) == wx.WXK_RETURN:
        print "hey"
print "what"
```