# How to record keybinds in python

Tags: python, keyboard

If a user clicks on multiple keys, it will print 'key1 + key2' and should print any key pressed on the keyboard. How would I go about this? I want it to work with any key, even function and F keys.

For example, a user clicks the keys `shift` and `F12`. `Shift + F12 was pressed` gets printed.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In order to get the keys combinations, you should display the message when a key is released, and check if another key is pressed at the same time.

Comment: i found a similar question w/ an answer
[the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17807994/15477801)

Comment: @SimonDev the question im asking is related to keyboard input from a physical input

Comment: @D_00 how would I go abouts doing this?

Comment: Idk I think this is the first step (you didn't know how and what to do; now you know what to do, but not how do to it) -- hope it's clear

Comment: You could use [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) to get the pressed and released keys, or [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) to get keys combinations.

Comment: I have approached a similar solution, it's just that with some keys it prints a 3 digit code.